# Minishift - How to compile assets using Laravel mix

Tags: php, laravel, openshift, openshift-origin, minishift

I have a minishift instance running on my laptop. I am running a Laravel app on it and it's configured to use a private git repository (a copy of repo is present on my laptop from where I push the changes to the git repository). Now my question is

How do I compile assets on it using laravel mix after I make CSS changes on my local repository and push them to the git repo?

Till now I have tried to:

Run `npm dev` by logging in to minishift using SSH. But it gives the error npm not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm package was added to the S2I base image only recently, it may not have got through to official images yet if using the Minishift from the CDK. It should have got through to CentOS based builder images that would be used by Origin based Minishift.

- https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-base-container/issues/115

Where did you get Minishift from and what version?

Comment: I have version 1.3.0 installed from this repository https://github.com/minishift/minishift/releases/tag/v1.3.0

Comment: And ``centos/php-70-centos7`` is being used? What do you get if you run ``oc describe is/php -n openshift``?

Comment: Yes it's the same. I cant paste the whole output here but this is a short summary -
7.0 (latest)
  tagged from centos/php-70-centos7:latest

Comment: It was 11 days ago

Comment: There is a version on Docker Hub from 3 days ago. As admin in the cluster try running ``oc import-image centos/php-70-centos7 -n openshift``. This should bring in the latest version.

Comment: Whoops, because there is already an image stream for ``php``, possibly should be ``oc import-image php -n openshift``.

Comment: Ok. I will try with this today. The earlier command returned `image not found` error